# Calling a node from another file

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I know that in programming it is important to keep things simple and be able to be changed. So to me that means it is important to use different files and functions and to keep them separate to easier isolate faults and improve readability.

I am new to C and I don't understand how to do this. I have my nodeTest.h

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct nodeTest
 {
     int data;
     struct nodeTest* next;

 };
```

Then I have another file trying to call that struct

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "nodeTest.h"

 nodeTest* first = (nodeTest*)malloc(sizeof(nodeTest));
```

I am getting an error saying that nodeTest is undeclared(not in function). What does that mean and why can I not use include to include a struct or typedef?

Comment: "nodeTest* first ..." is inside of a function right? C does not allow executable instructions except inside of a function.

Comment: Put your code inside a function named "main" for example.

Comment: Why can no one see that his issue is code outside of a function?

Comment: @CharlieBurns What do you mean? Can you elaborate on how to fix that.?

Comment: See my answer below about putting your code inside "main". If you don't want to use "main" use another name.

Comment: @CharlieBurns don't understand though, I just want a bunch of function for my linked list so I can call it from somewhere else. How do I do that? I am getting erros saying first is undeclared when I use it after main.

Comment: "I have my node.h"....followed by...."`#include "nodetest.h"`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths What is that suppose to mean?

Comment: @ripDaddy69: It means that if you define your struct in `node.h`, including `nodetest.h` in some other file probably isn't going to help you access it that much.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Why not?

Comment: @ripDaddy69: Because they're two different files.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Oh I see what you mean, that was a typo.That is not what i have on my cocmpute.r

Comment: See also [Using functions in C — declaring a variable and using it in multiple functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202376/using-functions-in-c-declaring-a-variable-and-using-it-in-multiple-functions).  Since that is a question asked later, it is a duplicate of this, rather than vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `struct NodeTest` instead of `NodeTest`.

Thats because C differentiates three namespaces:

- Namespace of structs.
- Namespace of type aliases (type names).
- Namespace of enums and unions.

So everywhere you want to use an struct, you have to specify the compiler that name refers to an struct. For example:

```
int main()
{
    struct NodeTest node;
}
```

One workaround to that problem is to specify an alias to that struct, to "add" the struct to the types namespace:

```
typedef NodeTest NodeTestType;

int main()
{
    NodeTestType node; //OK
}
```

Or using the common idiom, declare directly the struct as an alias:

```
typedef struct { ... } NodeTest;
```

Note that what this sentence does is to make an alias named `NodeTest` to an unnamed struct
you have declared in the same instruction.
One problem of this approach is that you cannot use the type inside the struct, because its not declared yet. You could workaround it naming the struct:

```
 typedef struct nodeTest //<-- Note that the struct is not anonimous
 {
     int data;
     struct nodeTest* next;
 } nodeTest;
```

Comment: @ripDaddy69 show us more code (The code where you are using the struct, for example). The context could help us to solve your problem. Whitout context, we have no idea about your error.

Comment: My code is exactly the same as what I posted except I changed it to a typedef struct like you said to.

Comment: @ripDaddy69 See my edit. Try to change malloc with NULL. NULL should work (Do only to test if thats the problem).

Comment: @Manu242726 I don't know how to do that, I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Within global scope, you can just declare / define functions, structures or global variables. You can not call a function just like that (literally "out of nowhere"). Create a `main`and call `malloc` from within:

```
int main(void) {
    nodeTest* first = (nodeTest*) malloc(sizeof(nodeTest));
    free(first);
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
struct nodeTest {
    int data;
    struct nodeTest* next;
};
```

defines `struct nodeTest` so

```
nodeTest* first;
```

is unknown to compiler. To solve this you could either use:

```
struct nodeTest* first;
```

or even better: use `typedef` while defining your `struct` and everything will be fine:

```
typedef struct nodeTest {
    int data;
    struct nodeTest* next;
} nodeTest ;
```

Comment: I get the same error regardless of if I have struct nodeTest or not.

Comment: @ripDaddy69: Try to change the definition to `typedef` (that should solve all troublesome occurrences of `nodeTest` identifier).

Comment: Oh strange, why was I unable to use a struct there?

Comment: @ripDaddy69: Without `typedef` you would have to use `struct` keyword before every single occurrence of `nodeTest`...

Comment: Actually I take that back, I am still getting an error, initializer element is not constant.

Comment: @ripDaddy69: Then you might want to edit your question, copy-paste the exact error your compiler gives you as well as the line that the error points out.

Comment: it is basically as you describe it to be the code isn't any different except I added the typedef struct and the name after it

Comment: @ripDaddy69: Frees the memory when you don't need it anymore. You should get some good book.

Comment: why would I do that? I need that to point to the front of my list the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define nodetest type

```
typedef struct nodeTest_t
 {
     int data;
     struct nodeTest_t* next;

 }nodeTest;
```

or else
 in main(), use `struct` keyword before nodeTest.

Comment: copy above definition into your first file. and then try.

Comment: It still doesn't work, the problem is the nodeTest* first = (nodeTest*)malloc(sizeof(nodeTest)); line –]

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code inside a function like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "nodeTest.h"

int main(void) {
    struct nodeTest* first = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeTest));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want a main quite yet I guess, I am trying to use this in another function that will be called in a main.

Comment: I still get an error that first doesn't exist when I call it in that same file.