# Using functions in C, declaring a variable and using it in multiple functions

Tags: c, struct

I want to make a linked list that is called from my main somewhere else. This linked list is made of nodes.

For example, this isn't my code just simplified version of it.

#### nodeTest.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct nodeTest
{
    int data;
    struct nodeTest* next;
};
```

Then I have another file trying to use that struct:

#### nodeTest.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include "nodeTest.h"

 int main(void) {
     struct nodeTest* first = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeTest));
     first->data = 0;
     return 0;
 }

void addLL(int data){
    if (first.data = 0)
    {
        printf("No head\n");
    }
}
```

I want first to be the first element in a linked list so how do I define an addElement to it that utilizes first? Right now when I call first I am getting an unrecognized error.

Here is where I get the error inside my linked list file after the main

```
void addLL(int data){
    if (head.data = 0)
```

I get the error at the if line, head is not recognized.

Comment: 1. You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program. 2. Please show actual code; your first `malloc` call isn't even in a function.

Comment: Why don't I need to return it? This is basically actual code. What needs to change? What do you need to see?

Comment: a code example that compiles; also what does the error look like?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201630/calling-a-node-from-another-file#19201630

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I don't think so, I wan to know more specifics about how this code works with the main file and calling other functions with a head specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Right. You get that error because the variable `head` is only visible from inside `main`. There are two ways around this:

1. You can declare `head` as a global variable, outside of any functions; or
2. You can pass `head` to any functions that need it as a pointer

Let's see how these options work:

### Using a global variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "nodeTest.h"

/* Declare a global variable. The initialization to NULL is redundant
 * since global variables are automatically initialized to zero. But
 * let's be thorough.
 */

struct nodeTest* head = NULL;

int main(void) {
   head = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeTest));
   /* check if head is NULL here. Just in case. */
   head->data = 0;

   addLL(1);

   return 0;
}

/* other functions here */
void addLL(int data) {
   /* since we allocate head in main it should never be NULL and
    * if it is, something is wrong. So assert.
    */
   assert(head != NULL);

   /* Notice: in your original code you had: if (first.data = 0)
    * which is wrong. First of all, there's no variable named first
    * declared anywhere. If you meant head, that should have been
    * head->first since head is a pointer. And lastly, first.data = 0
    * would set first.data to 0, instead of comparing it for equivalency, 
    * and would then cause the if to never execute because the compiler
    * would first set first.data to zero, then check first.data, and never
    * enter the loop since it was zero.
    */
   if (head->data == 0)
   {
      printf("No head");
      return;
   }

   /* other code here */
}
```

This version is easy and requires minimal changes. A benefit is that functions that need to modify head can easily do it.

It does require, in non-trivial programs, a lot of global variables though, which is considered bad programming practice and ought to be avoided if possible.

### Passing `head` as a pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "nodeTest.h"

int main(void) {
   struct nodeTest* head = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeTest));
   /* check if head is NULL here. Just in case. */
   head->data = 0;

   /* we call addLL, passing the head that we just allocated
    * to it.
    */
   addLL(1, head);
   return 0;
}

void addLL(int data, struct nodeTest *head) {
   if (head == NULL) || (head->data == 0))
   {
      printf("No head");
      return;
   }

   /* other code here */
}
```

This method requires that we pass `head` into every function that can need it. This complicates the function interface slightly but allows us more flexibility because we don't need to have many global variables for the many lists we'll have in our program.

But there is another problem. If any of those functions needs to modify the `head` pointer (for example, let's say you're deleting the first element in a list) then you have an issue. The pointer (which is *distinct* from the thing pointed to) is local to the function so any changes made to it will be invisible outside the function.

There are two ways to get around this issue:

1. Every function that accepts `head` as a parameter and may need to change it would have to return a pointer to the new head. This works but it can be cumbersome to implement and very prone to error.
2. Every function that accepts `head` as a parameter and may need to change it would accept a double pointer: a pointer to a pointer to the head. This works well but complicates things and may catch some novice programmers off-guard. It's also a bit prone to error but not as much as the previous option.

I hope that this answers your question, explains why you can't do what you did and the workarounds that exist.

Comment: first is undeclared in `first->data = 0;`

Comment: Oops - too much copy paste. Thanks @jev.

Comment: Sorry I had some typos  in there, I have two versions of code and I mixed them. One was test code that I was playing around with and the other was what I was working on. Just curious, if I have multiple instances of the linked list will a global variable behave any differently?

Comment: @NikBougalis What does AddLL do? It creates a new node with data as one?

Comment: @ripDaddy69: well, it is your function; I just called it. I'm not sure what you want it to do, but I guess from the name that it's supposed to add an entry to the linked list. How it does that depends on the requirements imposed on you. You can, if you want, ask a separate question on how to make `addLL` work, but I would suggest that you attempt to think it out first, using paper and pencil, and representing nodes as boxes and pointers by arrows. Then, if you can't work it out, ask again.

Comment: @ripDaddy69 if you have multiple instances of the linked list, you'd need multiple variables to represent them and, therefore, multiple functions (or some way of identifying which list a function should use). If you have multiple lists, you are pretty much required to use option 2 (which is the *sensible* approach anyways, even if a little more complicated).

Comment: But why do I want to addLL(1)? I know how to make it work, I am just very new to C and finding it incredibly frustrating because I know how all these data structures work but I don't know how to force C to do what I want it to do. I just need help with the syntax and programming quirks.

Comment: @ripDaddy69 You don't - I was just calling it to demonstrate how the two approaches differ (global vs. pointer). As for the syntax/quirks well... that's juts something you're going to have to grind through. You can, if you want, search for and look at a number of linked list implementations to get a feel for the language and how it works. The first result from Google pointed me to http://www.cprogramming.com/snippets/source-code/c-linked-list and although I didn't bother reading the code closely to verify that it's great, I think it would likely be a good start for you to see how things work.

Comment: @NikBougalis Is there some way to do this without a main function? I have another data structure that wants to call this one that will either have a main or be called from a source that has a main.

Comment: @ripDaddy69 the `main` function is where your program begins execution. You can do this from wherever you want, though, but it depends on which method you adopt on how you must implement things. If you show us actual code maybe we could help, but it really sounds to me that you should spend some time reading a book on C programming. If you have programming experience (it sounds like you do) then you should be able to pick up the basics relatively quickly.

Comment: @NikBougalis Yeah I am working through some online tutorials right now but I am just not familiar with how to declare the head in my linked list without a main in it as well.

Comment: @ripDaddy69 I suggest you start another question, showing us how your code is supposed to be called and what it's supposed to do (perhaps in English or in a language you're comfortable in) and *then* we can help or redirect you to the appropriate place where you can get help. But right now you're asking us: "I have ingredients, how do I make a cake?" and when we ask back "Well, here's a sample cake recipe." you reply "I know how to BBQ, but not bake. I'm watching food network to learn, but your recipe isn't for the kind of cake I want!" We simply must know more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 0: understanding of linked lists and C**

There is tons of material on that. Check out for instance these [slides from a lecture on data structures](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs281/f11/lectures/04-BasicADTs.pdf).

**Issue 1: 'head undeclared'**

Before you use a variable you need to introduce it first. The issue results from `head` not being in scope of the function (according to C rules). So you would need to pass a pointer to it as an argument:

```
void addLL(struct nodeTest *head, int data){
  // now you can access head->data, head->next
  // .. 
}
```

If you use `0` to signify that no data is available then you can't store any zeroes.
Another you could be to keep count of list elements and check if the count
is zero to determine whther the list is empty.

**Issue 2: 'first->data' undeclared**

Either declare first (same as with `head`), or use `head->data`.

**Issue 3: list design and API**

Using global state is generally agreed to be bad practice so don't use a global list. 
I'd recommend you to define another struct for the list and pass a point around ot the other function like `list_add()` or `list_remove()`, so you could also save a pointer to the last element to make appen an O(1) operation, e.g.:

```
struct list {
  struct node *first;
  struct node *last;
  unsigned long length;
};
```

So then, you can implement a function to check whether the list is empty:

```
inline bool list_is_empty(struct list* l) {
  assert(l != NULL);
  return l->length;  
}
```

And use multiple lists in your `main`:

```
 struct list *list1 = list_create(); // sets length to 0
 struct list *list2 = list_create(); // return a new list
 //...
 list_add(&list1, data); // you pass a pointer to the list to which you want to add
 //...
 struct node *e = list_search(&list1, data);
 if (e == NULL)
   printf("not found\n");
 //...
 list_remove(&list1, data);
 //
 list_destroy(&list1);
```

Adding an element to the list could be implemented like so:

```
int list_add(struct list* l, int data) {

    if (l == NULL)
        return LIST_FAILURE; // or exit with an error message

    l->last->next = list_elem_create(data); // dynamically creates a new node
    l->last = l->last->next;
    l->length++;
    return LIST_SuCCESS; // symbolc constant defined elsewhere 
}
```

Comment: What does that do and what does that mean?

Comment: I am not interested in adding elements to this list, I am more interested in searching the list for elements. What does *e do? I don't understand. What do you mean in a headerfile?

Comment: you said you want to create a linked list, so what is the interface you want to use? I suggest to separate the definition of the list and the one of the node so later you can use many different lists in your main

Comment: I don't really care about any of that right now I am just having a panic attac ktrying to get this done as fast as possible because I am so far behind in my work. I have to do this today. I have spent 8 hours on it already and I have made zero progress. I need to make progress or I am screwed.

Comment: so have you got a full list? you need to add elements to the list first so that you can later search for a particular one. best way forward would be to get the code you have to compile first and then iteratively improve it. what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: I am getting first undeclared for that line if (first.data == 0)

Comment: Where do you declare `first`?

Comment: int main(void) {
       struct nodeTest* first = malloc(sizeof(struct nodeTest));
       first->data = 0;
       return 0;
                      }


     void addLL(int data){
        if (first.data = 0)

Comment: That's not the code you posted in your question, you're just wasting everyone's time if you're posting fake code.

Comment: I have a couple versions of code I am working through and I accidently mixed two of them. Those are the only differences.

Comment: @Jev Thanks for all the help I am going through those slides trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot allocate memory before calling the main function. You can either declare a global variable outside main and use its address as the first. The alloc inside the main should work and thats the best way to do it. but you must typecast the struct something like below to be able to use it otherwise your compile will fail

```
typedef struct First {

<element 1>
struct first *next

} First;
```

then you can do this

```
First *first = NULL
first = (First *) malloc(sizeof(First));
```

Comment: doesn't look like this will compile